# vba: work with tables and remove duplicates with conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use VBA to copy multiple columns from a table (removing duplicates and applying some constraints) into another sheet. All this if possible, in tables formats.

I am very new to vba and I don't know if this is possible but what I would need is to take the unique product-store combinations from below so that sales are >0

```
Product  Store  day     sales
Apple      A   monday     3
Apple      A   tuesday    0
Apple      A   wednesday  4
Apple      B   thursday   7
Pear       A   monday     3
Pear       C   tuesday    0
```

Therefore, the result should be:

```
Product Store  
Apple      A   
Apple      B   
Pear       A
```

I have already tried to record the macro but the result is really long...

By the way, the data is quite large so I think that going line by line would not be an option.

Comment: If the result of your macro is long, but it works, you don't need a solution, you just need to make an improvement of your code.

Comment: If you require help then you need to provide more information, including the Macro Code you have produced, also what is and what is not working with the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

 Columns("A:D").Select 'Change to your actual cells that holds the data
 Selection.AutoFilter
 Columns("A:B").Select 'Change to your columns that holds the Products and Store data
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header :=xlNo 'Change to your columns that holds the Products and Store data
 Range("A1", Cells(Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 2)).Select 'Change to your columns that holds the Products and Store data
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
 ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should help:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False             'stop screen flickering
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  'prevent calculation while execution

    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your worksheet

    With ws
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'get last row with data from Column A

        'get unique records for product and store combined together
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If .Cells(i, 4).Value <> 0 Then 'consider product only if sales is not 0
                dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & "|" & .Cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & "|" & .Cells(i, 2).Value)
            End If
        Next

        With .Range("F2").Resize(dict.Count)    'unique product and store will be displayed from cell F2
            .Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
            .Offset(, 2).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Output will be as below:

[image]

Comment: @cdom - Did this help?